# Change filename before save file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-models

I have the next code to rename my files when upload in django admin (in models.py)

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return os.path.join('directory/', filename)

class Archivo(models.Model):
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to = get_file_path)
```

That works for me, but i want to pass the directory dynamically, something like this:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename, directory_string_var):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return os.path.join(directory_string_var, filename)
```

If i do that, i can't pass the directory parameter (variable) to the method in upload_to option of the "archivo" field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your goal is just preventing the files to fill up the given directory (this is a concern because depending on the filesystem, some operations over a directory with too many entries can be expensive), upload_to can contain strftime formatting, which will be replaced by the date/time of the upload.

```
archivo = models.FileField(upload_to = 'path/%Y/%M/%D/')
```

You can store the parameter in the instance object:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return os.path.join(instance.directory_string_var, filename)

class Archivo(models.Model):
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to = get_file_path)
    directory_string_var = 'default_directory_string_var'
```

Comment: thanks man, store the parameter in the instance work for me! :D

Comment: Mind explaining `uuid` in here?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari You can ignore this - it is a very old answer. The goal here was generating a unique name for every upload - I'm from Brazil where we speak Portuguese and sometimes people upload files with unicode or other characters that may cause problems down the road so I often use a hash or UUID instead of the original name. I probably would use `settings.SOMETHING` today.

Comment: This does not seem to work for Django 3.1.7 (way in the future from the original answer)

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
import uuid
import os

def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename_start = filename.replace('.'+ext,'')

    filename = "%s__%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(),filename_start, ext)
    return os.path.join('FolderPath', filename)

class Blast_Email(models.Model):
    file    = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path,verbose_name=(u'File'))
    ### your other columns
```