# dynamic FileField path

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use  `get_file_path` function  to generate dynamic path. Can I use `Album` slug field instead of this `str(instance.id)` in `get_file_path`? thanks

Here is models

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('files', str(instance.id), filename)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True,max_length=100,help_text="Suggested value automatically generated from name. Must be unique.")
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    albumid = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    music = models.ForeignKey(Music)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

Update: I tried `instance.slug` . Its not working. `instance.slug` does not exist in Song Model. Its only exists in Album model ( Want to use `Album` Slug field)
Update2: Here is model [snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/wB2QI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite straightforward: `str(instance.album.slug)`

Comment: DrTyrsa One thing more. Why its not working? `str(instance.category.name)`. Error message is `'Song' object has no attribute 'category'`

Comment: @no_access And why should it work? :-) I see no `category` in your code.

Comment: You are right. There is no `category` in this app. But It is in different `App`. But I'm using it in `Album Model`. Like `language = models.ForeignKey(Category)`

Comment: @no_access `str(instance.language.name)`

Comment: `'Song' object has no attribute 'language'`

Comment: @no_access Why are you using it with `Song` while it's for `Album`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `instance.slug` instead of `instance.id`

Another example you can find in the answer of post [Change filename before save file in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110581/change-filename-before-save-file-in-django)

*Update*: If not all instances have a slug field than you could be interested in a solution like this:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    fld = getattr(instance, 'slug', instance.id)
    return os.path.join('files', str(fld), filename)
```

Comment: I tried that but no luck. `instance.slug` does not exist in `Song` Model. Its only exists in `Album` model

Comment: I guess it is because `get_file_path` is called before `Album.slug` has received a value?!